# PostGIS: ST_LineMerge can make LineString from MultiLineString

Tags: postgis, geometry

I am trying to convert [MultiLineString](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DDKb8F6pB2/) to LineString with PostGIS:

[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT (st_astext(ST_LineMerge( geometry ))) AS shape
FROM   public."Cities"
where id = 364087;
```

but the result still is MultilineString:

[image]

Finally, I want to make a polygon :

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeValid(st_astext(ST_LineMerge( geometry)))) AS shape
FROM   public."Cities"
where id = 364087;
```

Comment: Do not forget about the [`ST_Dump()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) function

Comment: What's your question? You seem to have two tasks, but no problem description.

Comment: this is my question: I want to convert MultilineString to lineString. the reason is : after converting I want to make a polygon @Vince

Comment: Wanting to do something isn't a question. Not all  multi-part lines resolve to single-part, and not all linestrings can be polygons. You haven't provided the WKT of the geometry or asked a question.

Comment: I mean, I did try and I have a problem. So my question is this problem. @Vince

Comment: I added my example to my question @Vince

Comment: The purpose of StackExchange is to answer common problems. It isn't to solve *your* problem, but to solve problems *like* your problem. Answerable questions need to have a description of the problem with a reproducible example. Adding a link to an external site from which the data will be removed does not improve an incomplete problem description. It might help you, but that requires that others violate best security practice and follow your link, and the next person who comes along won't be able to benefit.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

We can see on the shape drawing that the lines are disconnected, so you won't be able to convert it to a single simple linestring.

You can however convert each part of the multiline to a single line using [`st_dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html), and then these simple lines can be converted to a polygon

```sql
with src(geom) as (values ('MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0),(10 10, 10 11, 11 11, 11 10, 10 10))'::geometry))
SELECT st_asText(ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ln.geom))
FROM (
  SELECT (st_dump(geom)).geom
  FROM src) ln;
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))
 POLYGON((10 10,10 11,11 11,11 10,10 10))
(2 rows)
```

Comment: How can I set mu geometry columnt to this part ? with src(geom) as (values ('MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0),(10 10, 10 11, 11 11, 11 10, 10 10))'::geometry))
 @JGH

Comment: this line is for the example. Remove it, and replace `from src` by the query you are using to get the geometries

Comment: I am using query like this https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cxWcN2Jg5q/ but I got error [XX000] ERROR: lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed @JGH

Comment: so your lines are not ready to be transformed to polygons (must be closed, i.e. the 1st and last points are the same) and have at least 4 points

Comment: Thanks my friend, My big problem Is here, I don't know How can I close the lines. Or how do I have to know which lines need to be closed @JGH

Comment: This is your suggestion code https://ibb.co/108QrYJ and I have these result @JGH

Comment: this would be a new, different question. Explain what you have, what you have tried (you are expected to make some research before asking) and what doesn't work.

Comment: Ok , thanks ,Let m ask other question, Thanks my friend